# Any way to list the contents of a 2GP (second generation package)?

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package, 2gp, second-generation-packaging, packaging-2

I have an obscure error when installing a 2GP beta package about a component I don't expect to be the in the package.

Is there a way to list the contents of a package given just a package version Id 04txxxxxxxxxxxx? I couldn't see anything in the [Package Commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm) list.

Comment: Given the [partner forum poll](https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00005T6xmS) that Dileep Burki initiated on this subject, the answer is likely "no". The expectation is currently that you tag your git commit that was used to generate the 2GP so you know what is in it from the git perspective.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Would be good to look into my current version rather than carefully re-create a version from Git source but so be it.

Comment: I think the point with 2GP is that git is the source of truth. Yes, the problem is you have to remember to tag it when you create the package version (but you could easily write a script that always does the two together).

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. I'm trying to diagnose an error where when I install the package I get a complaint about a component name that is not in Git so am trying ti figure out what is going on.

Oh repeating the packaging made the problem go away. So Likely on first packaging a spurious file way present.

Comment: And that's another problem with 2GP - it doesn't operate directly from the version control system, but rather indirectly via a file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think there is a way to see it from the command line, right before installing the package in the browser (from `yoursalesforcedomain.my.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t.......`) there is a **View Components** link that will show the list of metadata in the package.

[image][image]

Comment: That would have helped me the other day... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Install the package then go to Setup -> Installed Packages and click on the package name then click the View Components button to see the list of components.

(This doesn't solve the problem for the case I had where the install failed but worth remembering.)